# Updating maven-metadata.xml when publishing to an SFT Resolver with SBT

Tags: maven, sbt, maven-metadata

I'm trying to publish artifacts to an SFTP resolver. After some initial struggle, the following configuration works fine:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.sftp("foo-resolver", "domain", 22, "path/to/repo")
  .as("me", new java.io.File("path/to/key")))
```

The issue I'm having is that this doesn't create or update the `maven-metadata.xml` file, even though I've enabled the maven resolver plugin (`addMavenResolverPlugin`).

I feel the problem is linked to the SFTP resolver, since replacing my `publishTo` as follows *will* create / update `maven-metadata.xml`:

```
publishTo := Some("foo-resolver" at "file:////path/to/some/local/folder")
```

Is there some limitation inherent to the SFTP resolver? I couldn't find any hint of this in the documentation - if anything, the 0.13.8 release notes (http://notes.implicit.ly/post/114141158904/sbt-0138) seem to imply it should work:

> Additionally, sbt will now be able to fully construct maven-metadata.xml files when publishing to remote repositories

I'm using SBT 0.13.13.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue while trying to publish my jar to the AWS codeartifact.

Adding the plugin `sbt-maven-resolver` to the `plugins.sbt` fixed the issue :

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-maven-resolver" % "0.1.0")
```

when you run `sbt assembly` after adding the plugin, the `maven-metadata.xml` file will be created (which solves the problem)